# Typeform not returning response answers in order of typeform

Tags: json, rest, api, typeform

Does anyone know why with Typeform v1 I could get the response answers back and they would be in the same order everytime, but now in v2 they return a different order every time a request is made. I'm at a complete loss as to how I'm supposed to manage entering users answers in the database now and line them up with the questions because there's no consistent order coming from the response.

So far, I haven't been able to receive a response from Typeform about this.

Here are images of 3 responses from a typeform that return a different order of answers each time. (see: choice > label)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA3aX.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps6Qi.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ef4Z.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Typeform [Webhooks](https://developer.typeform.com/webhooks/)?

I think it's an easier solution for what you are trying to achieve.
You will get notified on the URL of your choice every time a form is filled.

You can then extract the payload and store in database of your choice.

Also you could use `id` of fields instead of position in the `answers` array.

What you have now (more or less):

```
first_name = answers[0].text
last_name = answers[1].text
```

But index of fields in `answers` array is not consistent, so instead you should have something like that using field ids.

```
first_name = answers.filter(a => f.field.id == "ID_OF_FIRST_NAME_FIELD")
last_name = answers.filter(a => f.field.id == "ID_OF_LAST_NAME_FIELD")
```

This solution would work every time as it's not depend on the order.

Hope it helps

Comment: Not sure this makes a lot of sense. Thanks anyways! I've received a response from Typeform stating that there is a problem with the response API and that it does return the results randomly and that they are working on a solution currently. I don't quite understand why this was changed, because they were returning the answers array in order before in version 1. So, goodbye Typeform! Hello custom solution using my own API and Vue.js! I love having excuses to write more code.

Comment: I was just trust trying to show you that there are other ways of achieving the same thing, in a more reliable way, and works with the current Typeform API.

Comment: What I meant was that I don't see how this makes sense given the images. Maybe you could expound more. Thanks!

Comment: Webhooks are an alternative, and could be a better implementation, as it's real time.

Your server will receive each individual answer when they are submitted, instead of you calling the `Responses API` so often and iterate over it.

+ the answers are in order, so that's a solution until Typeform fix ordering on their Responses API

Also I offer another solution to extract answers, based on `id` instead of index in the array. This will work 100% of time, no matter the index of the answer.

Comment: I see the field.id in the response (images), but I don't see them anywhere in the Typeform GUI on Typeform. Where can I find those on Typeform to add them to my loop for comparison? Thanks again!

Comment: You can see `id` and `ref` properties looking at your form definition by calling `http://api.typeform.com/forms/{YOUR_FORM_ID}`
There you will see all your fields and their corresponding `id` or `ref`